# Tunneling proxy on VS 2008

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008, proxy, tunnel

Is there a way to tunnel a proxy to access a remote sql server database on visual studio 2008?
I'm working in a project at college that uses a sql server database but the access is restricted to the internal network. I'd like to access the database from my home too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Please* talk to your local systems or network admin before doing this. They likely either have a system already in place, or forbid it per policy

Comment: I've already talked with the admin and he said that the access outside the network is not granted.
XD

Comment: Then you obviously shouldn't do an end-run with Hamachi or some zero-conf VPN!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [setup a VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68799/setting-up-a-vpn) easily...

Take a look to [Hamachi](http://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/vpn.asp?lang=es) and [Rebombo](http://www.remobo.com/), very easy 0 configuration vpn...

Answer (score 1):

In the event VPN access is not granted and the highly unlikely event that the SQL Server is exposed through the firewall, could you not get a copy of (or subset of) the database for development on local machine?

Answer (score 0):

If the colledge has VPN set up, you can set up the VPN on your computer to access the database from home.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [vpn](http://world-secure-channel.com/why/) service,it works really well